# Openssl -sign gives different result in CMD vs PowerShell

Tags: powershell, cmd, openssl, base64

I have the following code in Powershell:

```
$headerEncoded=openssl base64 -in header.json -A
$payloadEncoded=openssl base64 -in payload.json -A

$headerEncoded=$headerEncoded.Split('=')[0].Replace('+', '-').Replace('/', '_')
$payloadEncoded=$payloadEncoded.Split('=')[0].Replace('+', '-').Replace('/', '_')

$toBeSigned=$headerEncoded + "." + $payloadEncoded

$toBeSigned | Out-File -Encoding "UTF7" toBeSigned.txt -NoNewLine

openssl dgst -sha256 -sign jwtRS256.key toBeSigned.txt | openssl enc -base64 -A
```

In the last row in Powershell I try to sign the header + payload. However I get a different result in Powershell (wrong) as I run the same command in cmd.

Result Powershell:
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

Result CMD:
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

Content toBeSigned.txt:

ew0KICAiYWxnIjogIlJTMjU2IiwNCiAgImtpZCI6ICJ0ZXN0LWF1dG9tYXRpb24iDQp9.ew0KICAiZ2l2ZW5fbmFtZSI6ICJOaWNrIiwNCn0

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem resides with the pipe `|` in the last line of your script.  In essence, the encoding is getting messed-up.

Here's a potential quick fix for the last line:

```
$toBeEncoded=openssl dgst -sha256 -sign jwtRS256.key toBeSigned.txt
$toBeEncoded | Out-File -Encoding "Default" toBeEncoded.txt -NoNewLine

openssl enc -base64 -A -in toBeEncoded.txt
```

If you want, you can add an `-out jwtEncoded.txt` at the end of the last `openssl` line here.

Comment: This will still gives me a different result unfortunately

Comment: If necessary, adjust the `-Encoding` of Out-File to match your system.  Otherwise, always use the `-out file` parameter of openssl, rather than rely on its stdout encoding in cmd vs. PS.  Of course, this means you'd need to read-in the file contents after file creation.